# How does umask affect ACLs?

Tags: linux, permissions, posix, acl

Can someone explain to me how `umask` affects the default mask of newly created files if ACLs are activated? Is there some documentation about this?

Example:

```sh
$ mkdir test_dir && cd test_dir
$ setfacl -m d:someuser:rwx -m u:someuser:rwx .  # give access to some user
$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: myUsername
# group: myGroup
user::rwx
user:someuser:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:someuser:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
$ umask # show my umask
077
$ echo "main(){}" > x.c # minimal C program
$ make x # build it
cc     x.c   -o x
$ getfacl x
# file: x
# owner: myUsername
# group: myGroup
user::rwx
user:someuser:rwx           #effective:rw-
group::---
mask::rw-
other::---
```

I would expect `mask:rwx`. Actually after setting `umask` to e.g. `027` I get the expected behavior.

Comment: With a umask of 077, you'll get a `mask::rw-`. But that isn't really your question, correct?

Comment: @slm This is part of my question. I want to know how the mask of new files depends on the umask. I was quite surprised that with 077 I get `mask::rw-` and not `mask::rwx` which was the default mask of the directory.

Comment: OK, I'm updating my answer now with examples which should help to clear this up. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: This [question](http://serverfault.com/q/352783/139457) is closely related.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this example, titled: [ACL and MASK in linux](http://kmaiti.blogspot.com/2011/09/acl-and-mask-in-linux.html). In this article the following examples are demonstrated which I think help to understand how ACL's and `umask` interact with each other.

#### Background

When a file is created on a Linux system the default permissions `0666` are applied whereas when a directory is created the default permissions `0777` are applied.

#### example 1 - file

Suppose we set our umask to 077 and touch a file. We can use `strace` to see what's actually happening when we do this:

```
$ umask 077; strace -eopen touch testfile 2>&1 | tail -1; ls -l testfile
open("testfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
-rw-------. 1 root root 0 Sep 4 15:25 testfile
```

In this example we can see that the system call `open()` is made with the permissions 0666, however when the `umask 077` is then applied by the kernel the following permissions are removed (`---rwxrwx`) and we're left with `rw-------` aka 0600.

#### example - 2 directory

The same concept can be applied to directories, except that instead of the default permissions being 0666, they're 0777.

```
$ umask 022; strace -emkdir mkdir testdir; ls -ld testdir
mkdir("testdir", 0777)                  = 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Jul  9 10:55 testdir
```

This time we're using the `mkdir` command. The `mkdir` command then called the system call `mkdir()`. In the above example we can see that the `mkdir` command called the `mkdir()` system call with the defaul permissions `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx`). This time with a umask of `022` the following permissions are removed (`----w--w-`), so we're left with 0755 (`rwxr-xr-x`) when the directories created.

#### example 3 (Applying default ACL)

Now let's create a directory and demonstrate what happens when the default ACL is applied to it along with a file inside it.

```
$ mkdir acldir
$ sudo strace -s 128 -fvTttto luv setfacl -m d:u:nginx:rwx,u:nginx:rwx acldir

$ getfacl --all-effective acldir
# file: acldir
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rwx
user:nginx:rwx          #effective:rwx
group::r-x          #effective:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:nginx:rwx      #effective:rwx
default:group::r-x      #effective:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Now let's create the file, `aclfile`:

```
$ strace -s 128 -fvTttto luvly touch acldir/aclfile

# view the results of this command in the log file "luvly"
$ less luvly
```

Now get permissions of newly created file:

```
$ getfacl --all-effective acldir/aclfile 
# file: acldir/aclfile
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rw-
user:nginx:rwx          #effective:rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Notice the mask, `mask::rw-`. Why isn't it `mask::rwx` just like when the directory was created?

Check the `luvly` log file to see what default permissions were used for the file's creation:

```
$ less luvly |grep open |tail -1
10006 1373382808.176797 open("acldir/aclfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3 <0.000060>
```

This is where it get's a little confusing. With the mask set to `rwx` when the directory was created, you'd expect the same behavior for the creation of the file, but it doesn't work that way. It's because the kernel is calling the `open()` function with the default permissions of `0666`.

#### To summarize

- Files won't get execute permission (masking or effective). Doesn't matter which method we use: ACL, umask, or mask & ACL.
- Directories can get execute permissions, but it depends on how the masking field is set.
- The only way to set execute permissions for a file which is under ACL permissions is to manually set them using `chmod`.

#### References

- [acl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl)

Comment: @jofel - let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @sIm thank you very much for your detailed answer. It brings me closer to my actual problem: The group permission in the chmod syscall affects the mask of the file (`chmod("file",0760)` -> `mask:rw`,  `chmod("file",0770)` -> `mask:rwx` ). Maybe I should start a new question about this...

Comment: @jofel - yes that sounds like another question.

Comment: @sIm and it was already answered [here](http://serverfault.com/a/352915/139457).

Comment: _"When a file is created on a Linux system the default permissions 0666 are applied..."_ -- well that's not exactly right, since it's up to the creating application.

Answer (score 2):

for security purposes, the linux operating system doesn't allow for the automatic creation of a file with an execute bit. This is to prevent cyber attackers from writing programs into such files and executing them if they gain access to your server. It's just a safety precaution. You'll forever have to manually set the execute bit on files after creating them with the chmod utility