# Default permission not taken into account after setfacl

Tags: permissions, acl

I'm trying to set default permissions so that all files created in my folder hackerank would be created with rwx by default.

I've done a `chmod g+s` (as I was looking at different threads, not sure this did anything to be honest, but just in case it changes anything):

```
chmod g+s hackerank/
```

and then tried to set default ACLs on the group:

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx hackerank/
```

If I check ACLs, they now look good:

```
getfacl hackerank/
# file: hackerank/
# owner: will
# group: will
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:will:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

But I create a new file, it still inherits `-rw-rw-r--+` (the + showing the ACL attributes are in effect:

```
touch hackerank/test
ll hackerank/
total 8.0K
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 will will 4.0K Jul 11 16:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 will will 4.0K Jul 11 15:03 ../
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 will will    0 Jul 11 16:09 test

getfacl hackerank/test
# file: hackerank/test
# owner: will
# group: will user::rw-
group::rwx  #effective:rw-
group:will:rwx  #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Any clue as to what I have missed?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `getfacl test` plz!

Comment: `getfacl hackerank/test`
`# file: hackerank/test`
`# owner: will`
`# group: will`
`user::rw-`
`group::rwx   #effective:rw-`
`group:will:rwx   #effective:rw-`
`mask::rw-`
`other::r--`

Answer (score 1):

See also this question from just two months earlier: [setting 'x' (executable) bit using ACL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358494/setting-x-executable-bit-using-acl).  There's a nice pointer to where this is defined in the official documentation, in [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358494/setting-x-executable-bit-using-acl/359016#359016).

---

Applications create files with a given mode.  The mode is then limited, but never extended, by the current `umask`:

```
strace touch a
...
open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
```

e.g. I have a `umask` of 002 which limits the above created file to `0664/-rw-rw-r--` (viewed with `stat a`).

My understanding is this limits ACLs as well.  <del>ACLs are not permitted to exceed the permissions that you see when you read the mode of a file, so</del>

The access by group `will` on your file cannot exceed `rw-`.  This is enforced by the `mask` ACL... thing, which explains the "effective" comments in the output of getfacl.  EDIT: the mask applies to all ACL entries except for "user::" (the file owner) and "other:".  All such ACL entries are limited by the mask.

<del>The access by users and groups other than `will` and `will` cannot exceed `r--`.</del>

Comment: Ok, I'll need to look into `umask` and `strace` to understand what you did there, but I get the general idea and I know where to keep looking now.
Thanks!