# Permissions from file and sub directory for all users inherit permanet

Tags: linux, files, permissions, directory

Hi I have a directory `/home/nvs-upload/media/ImageFtp/` and the directory `ImageFTP` have many sub directory. The issue than I have is than a job run and add new sub directory it add to the new directory the permission `755` and the files inside `644`. I will like to add automatically to the new directory and files the permission `777`. not matter the user or group.

what command I have to run to do this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set directories to `777` and files to `666`, respectively, by defining default values as `ACL` entries:

```
setfacl -m default:u::rwx -m default:g::rwx -m default:o::rwx /home/nvs-upload/media/ImageFtp
```

(use the `-R` option to recursively also apply this to already existing files and directories). Here we set the default values for the `u`ser, `g`roup and `o`thers to `rwx`.

Please note that you:

**a**) have to have the drive mounted with `ACL`s enabled (on standard UNIX FSs these are mostly activated by default these days) and

**b**) you cannot make files executable by default as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358494/setting-x-executable-bit-using-acl) and the discussions linked there.

Comment: I use the long versions of parameters for low-rep users nowadays, (`--recursive`) but **+1** anyway as I was going to say the exact same thing!  **;-)**

Comment: Excellent it work Good.

Comment: But In linux of amazon show me Operation not supported. It was work on Centos 7. who I can do to set it on Amazon Linux AMI?

Comment: @Angel Sorry, I am not familiar with this flavour. Try using using the output of `mount` to see what filesystem you are using and then check in `/proc/fs/<repective filesystem>/<partition>/options` for an `acl` entry. If none is given you might be able to remount with the `acl` option - given that the FS supports it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish change permission for your files and folders recursively, you need use command chmod with -R: `sudo chmod -R 777 your_folder/` In this case directory your_folder and all files and subdirectorys it includes will get permissions 777.